# How to conduct a multipart upload to a Digital Ocean space via AWS SDK boto3?

Tags: python, digital-ocean, bucket

I am trying to establish the correct way of initiating and handling a multi-part upload to a Digital Ocean using the boto3 SDK.

So far I have been able to create a Space (Bucket) via the SDK, but past that the documentation I can find really doesn't cover much else in direct relation to Digital Ocean spaces.
Below is what I have tried when attempting to initiate a multipart upload, which returns the error: *'S3' object has no attribute 'initiate_multipart_upload*

```
client = session.client('s3',
                            region_name=str(region),
                            endpoint_url='https://{REGION}.digitaloceanspaces.com'.format(REGION=region),
                            aws_access_key_id=str(constants.DIGITAL_OCEAN_API_KEY),
                            aws_secret_access_key=str(constants.DIGITAL_OCEAN_API_SECRET_KEY))

response = client.initiate_multipart_upload(Bucket=bucket_id,Key=chunk_data)
```

Comment: This is the documentation I am referring too >>> https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html?highlight=list_objects_v2#S3.Client.create_multipart_upload

Comment: boto3 is for working with AWS resources. It will not work with Digital Ocean.

Comment: @jmkmay Are you sure about this?

Comment: Lol yes. When you use `session.client('s3', ...)` you are connecting to an S3 bucket. Notice the parameter "aws_access_key". That's an AWS key not Digital Ocean key. You're probably looking for [something like this...](https://developers.digitalocean.com/libraries/)

Comment: https://developers.digitalocean.com/documentation/spaces/#aws-s3-compatibility

Comment: I am afraid you appear to be incorrect on this one. Also, as I mentioned the question, I have managed to create a space (bucket) using the boto3 SDK.

Comment: Yea so that's a little horrifying... I would use a tool built for the job. This is like taking a Ford F150 motor, putting it in a Chevy, wiring it up correctly and telling others to do the same because it runs. Just use a Chevy motor.

Comment: If you know of such a tool, pray do tell. I'm stuck with open support ticket trying to figure this s**t out. I only used boto3 as its clearly stated at the very top of DO docs that they are fully compatible and use was recommended. Digital oceans docs are among the worst I have ever come across!

Comment: I'm sorry about your experience. I've never used DigitalOcean and have always defaulted to AWS because they are extremely developer friendly. Could you try using [the Rest API](https://developers.digitalocean.com/documentation/v2/) with a Python library like requests? There are also a couple of community alternatives [like this one](https://github.com/koalalorenzo/python-digitalocean) though on first inspection I'm not sure if that deals with spaces or just drops.

Comment: I think you are right. I’m going with AWS. Appreciate the link but as you pointed out it doesn’t cover my requirements. Cheers